# list all data in main table and check the other table with criteria

Tags: sql

I have two tables `staffdetails` and `worklog` with staff's start time and finish time. I am looking for a result that lists some staff they are not started work when we executing this SQL please refer below example:

- `staffdetails` table

  ```
  stafid  staffnm
  ------  -------
  100200  John
  100201  Jenny
  100203  Camas
  ```
- `Worklog` table

  ```
  stfid   startime   finishtime
  ------  ---------  ----------
  100200  11.30 p.m  12.30 p.m
  100201  10.00 a.m  10.30 a.m
  100200  12.35 p.m  12.40. p.m
  100200  12.45 p.m
  100203  1.30 p.m   2.30 p.m
  300200  10.0 p.m   6.00 p.m
  ```
- The output

  ```
  staffid   stafname
  -------   --------
  100203    Camas
  100201    Jenny
  ```

Comment: Can you append the query you have currently?

Answer (score 1):

Use `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT s.Name, s.staffId
FROM staffdetails s
LEFT JOIN working w ON w.staffid = s.staffid
WHERE w.staffId IS NULL;
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/031e9/8)

**Update:** If you want to get unmatched list of the two tables you can combine two `LEFT JOIN`s with a `UNION ALL` like so:

```
SELECT s.Name, s.staffId
FROM staffdetails s
LEFT JOIN working w ON w.staffid = s.staffid
WHERE w.staffId IS NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT w.Name, w.staffId
FROM working w
LEFT JOIN staffdetails s ON w.staffid = s.staffid
WHERE s.staffId IS NULL;
```

### [Updated SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ce7ec/3)

Comment: thank you for your reply but it list only the data not in working table but in staffdetails

Comment: The above sql lists all the unmatched records. Actullaty I am looking for a list that Id and name will take from staff details table and then it looks the working table for any staff is there their time is not entered.example. 100200-Glen 11.10 pm,100201-John 9.30 Am,100203-Lily nil,etc

Comment: @firozapasaripoil - Sorry I can't understand you. Can you please update your question with some sample data and the desired output.